# passport-apple is not returning the user email

Tags: node.js, passport.js, sign-in-with-apple

I have the following code

```
passport.use(new AppleStrategy({
    clientID: process.env.APPLE_CLIENT_ID,
    teamID: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
    callbackURL: process.env.BASE_SERVER_URL + "/api/user/apple-login-callback",
    keyID: process.env.APPLE_KEY_ID,
    privateKeyLocation: "./keys/d.p8",
    passReqToCallback: true
}, function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, idToken, profile, cb) {
    // The idToken returned is encoded. You can use the jsonwebtoken library via jwt.decode(idToken)
    // to access the properties of the decoded idToken properties which contains the user's
    // identity information.
    // Here, check if the idToken.sub exists in your database!
    // idToken should contains email too if user authorized it but will not contain the name
    // `profile` parameter is REQUIRED for the sake of passport implementation
    // it should be profile in the future but apple hasn't implemented passing data
    // in access token yet https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/tokenresponse

    cb(null, idToken);

    // User.login(username, password).then(result => {
    //     const payload = {
    //         sub: result[0].id
    //     };
    //     // create a token string
    //     const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
    //
    //     return done(null, token, result[0]);
    // }).catch(err => {
    //     console.dir(err);
    //     return done(null, false);
    // });
}));
```

Unfortunately, I'm not getting the user email or other information from passport. The user is redirected to sign in with apple, but when apple redirects back to my site, this code above is triggered, but it doesn't grab the user's email address or info. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to grab the user information from the req parameter. But attention: Apple provides the name just for the first sign up. You should store the provided data with the unique id token in your database. Every subsequent sign in will provide the id token, which you can use to get the user data from your DB.

Also, you can use "jsonwebtoken" library for decoding the idToken to get the email address from it.